# R - repeat rows in a data frame based on a splitted datetime interval

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, split

I have a data frame like this:

```
workplace = c('wp1','wp1','wp1')
state = c("working", "stopped", "working")
startdate = as.POSIXct(c('2010-11-1 4:53.12','2010-11-1 5:25.43','2010-11-1 5:31.43'))
enddate = as.POSIXct(c('2010-11-1 5:25.43','2010-11-1 5:31.43','2010-11-1 5:32.02'))
timeline = data.frame(workplace, state, startdate, enddate)

# Printed looks like this
#  workplace   state           startdate             enddate
#1       wp1 working 2010-11-01 04:53:00 2010-11-01 05:25:00
#2       wp1 stopped 2010-11-01 05:25:00 2010-11-01 05:31:00
#3       wp1 working 2010-11-01 05:31:00 2010-11-01 05:32:00
```

My intention is to create a time series with intervals of 15 minutes and assign each row to its corresponding interval, repeating the row and splitting the startdate-enddate interval if it takes more than the assigned 15 minutes interval. The example given should look like this in the end:

```
#  workplace   state           startdate             enddate            interval
#1       wp1 working 2010-11-01 04:53:00 2010-11-01 05:00:00 2010-11-01 04:45:00
#2       wp1 working 2010-11-01 05:00:00 2010-11-01 05:15:00 2010-11-01 05:00:00
#3       wp1 working 2010-11-01 05:15:00 2010-11-01 05:25:00 2010-11-01 05:15:00
#4       wp1 stopped 2010-11-01 05:25:00 2010-11-01 05:30:00 2010-11-01 05:15:00
#5       wp1 stopped 2010-11-01 05:30:00 2010-11-01 05:31:00 2010-11-01 05:30:00
#6       wp1 working 2010-11-01 05:31:00 2010-11-01 05:32:00 2010-11-01 05:30:00
```

I have managed to add the interval column with this piece of code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(xts)
timeline = cbind(timeline,interval=align.time(timeline$startdate - lubridate::minutes(15), n=60*15))
```

Now I need to split the datetime interval between `startdate` and `enddate` of each row in intervals of 15 minutes starting from the `interval` date, and repeat the rows "n" 15 minutes interval times. I have tried creating a sequence with `seq.POSIXt(timeline$interval, timeline$enddate, by=60*15)` but cannot be used with columns. How could I do this split for each row and repeat it the number of intervals created by `seq.POSIXt`? Could it be any other approach easier than the one I am looking for?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have managed to build the data frame fractioning the datetime intervals in absolute intervals of quarter of hour. Instead of using the lubridate or xts packages, I have been able to do it with a custom function and the help of the data.table package. Here is the full script in case it helps someone with the same needs in the future. It can be used with any interval duration that could fit in 60 minutes.

```
workplace = c('wp1','wp1','wp1')
state = c("working", "stopped", "working")
startdate = as.POSIXct(c('2010-11-1 4:53.12','2010-11-1 5:25.43','2010-11-1 5:31.43'))
enddate = as.POSIXct(c('2010-11-1 5:25.43','2010-11-1 5:31.43','2010-11-1 5:32.02'))
timeline = data.frame(workplace, state, startdate, enddate)

library(data.table)
timeline = as.data.table(timeline)

intervalMinutes = 15L
intervalSeconds = 60L * intervalMinutes

# Function to get the absolute quarter of hour
alignInterval = function(x) {
  hourInterval = trunc(x, "hour")
  hourInterval + ((as.integer(x - hourInterval) %/% intervalSeconds) * intervalSeconds)
}

# For the original start date and end date, create the columns with the corresponding absolute quarter of hour
timeline[,`:=`(startDateInterval = alignInterval(startDate),
           endDateInterval = alignInterval(endDate))]
# Now create a new column with the number of absolute intervals between the start and end
timeline[,numIntervals := as.integer(endDateInterval - startDateInterval) %/% intervalSeconds + 1L]

# Repeat each row depending on the value of the new column with the number of intervals
timeline = timeline[rep( seq(1, .N), numIntervals),]

# Set the absolute quarter of hour corresponding to each repeated row multiplying 15 minutes by the number in sequence of the group of workplace, state and startDate
timeline[,interval := startDateInterval + (intervalSeconds*(seq(.N)-1)),.(workplace,state,startDate)]

# Adding 15 minutes to the interval start date we will have the end date of each interval
timeline[,intervalEnd:= interval + intervalSeconds]

# Fix the start date in the intermediate intervals
timeline[startDate < interval, startDate := interval]

# Fix the end date in the intermediate intervals
timeline[endDate > intervalEnd, endDate := intervalEnd]

# Clear the columns created for calculation purposes
timeline[,`:=`(startDateInterval = NULL,
          endDateInterval = NULL,
          intervalEnd = NULL,
          numIntervals = NULL)]
```